# Not understanding something with JSON Web Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I'm just getting started with JWT and I've been going through some examples and posts but one thing I don't understand and no one seems to touch on is how .Net knows which controller to go to.

Example: In one example they used a controller called MainController that had the CreateToken/ValidateToken code but in others it seems that most use TokenController for their code. My question is how does .Net know that when I put [Authorize] on my API ActionResult that it will route to say TokenController as apposed to MainController? I'm not seeing anything in the examples that seems to let .Net know which controller to use to run the JWT code.

Here is one example I've been looking at.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-2-creating-and-validating-jwt-json-web-token/

I would have thought it would be in the Startup.cs but I'm not seeing where it says use TokenController or maybe MainController.

```
private void SetupJWTServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string key = "my_secret_key_12345"; //this should be same which is used while creating token    
            var issuer = "http://example.com";  //this should be same which is used while creating token

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = true,
                  ValidateAudience = true,
                  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                  ValidIssuer = issuer,
                  ValidAudience = issuer,
                  IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
              };

              options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                  {
                      if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                      {
                          context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                      }
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  }
              };
          });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Its in the middleware that runs when you Add()/Use() whatever your chosen mechanism is in Startup.

Comment: @Crowcoder I added more to my initial question. I don't see anything in the Startup.cs that tells it the controller to use for Authentication or Authorization.

Comment: its in the `Configure()` method. `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Comment: @Crowcoder so how does it know to route to my TokenController? What if I wanted to call my controller JWTController? How would I set it to go there instead of say TokenController?

Comment: Your application does not issue nor validate the token, it is the issuer, "http://example.com" in your example. The `[Authorize]` is strictly the client requiring autnN/authZ for the caller of your API. Generally you don't also implement an identity provider in the same application that relies on the provider for tokens. I think you might want to read up on identity providers to understand the difference between the client and the provider.